# adding EventListeners to gmail send button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I am writing a Chrome extension which will pull information from each email you send and store it in a spreadsheet. I'm writing the content scripts in javascript.

I want it to start pulling the information when you click the send button, so I obviously need to attach an event listener to it like so:

```
var el = document.getElementById("some_ID");
el.addEventListener('build', function(e){...}, false);
```

However, gmail dynamically assigns id to the various elements of the page so I cannot know in advance what to put in for the element id.

My question is how to get around this? I'm sure there is some other way to attach the event listener or to get at the DOM node that the "send" button is at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the standard gmail dialog that pops up when composing an email you can traverse to the send button like this:

```
document.querySelector('table .HE td div[role="button"][data-tooltip^="Send"]')
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('table .HE td div[role="button"][data-tooltip^="Send"]')[0]
```

Going to Gmail and clicking compose you can then type the above into the console and that will get you to the send button.

That might not be working though if user switches to a pop-out window.
In general that might be very brittle too. As soon as gmail changes the way they show the dialog you have to change your selector too.

Comment: @user2215033: Has this helped at all?

Comment: Hi Francois, thanks for your reply. Yes this does the job required so thank you for that. However, as you pointed out it will be very brittle. So at present I am trying to come up with some other way to achieve the same affect. If/when I figure it out I'll post it here.

Comment: Hi @FrançoisWahl can you give me little bit idea about how to abort email when send button already click. as i am using gmail.js of kartik talwar

Comment: @HarshalPatil: I'm not familiar with gmail.js but I would think that ones you clicked send that it goes to the server and you have no longer any control over the email, unless, gmail has a "recall" feature exposed through their API or similar.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl So there is any other to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a similar extension.
The selector like you wrote works, but the problem is that the "send" button appears only when a composer exists.

When the composer doesn't exist, or has been closed, the listener dies.
Right?
By now I've an "interval" that checks if the button exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-tooltip` can change depending on the language, I'm using the following selector

```
$("[role=dialog] table .HE td div[role=button]").first();
```

but it only works when creating a new email (not replying or forward)

Here another way thats working for me:

```
$(".gU.Up div[role=button]");
```